# Invalid Date Format Returned To Controller from Control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

**The Problem**

I am using a Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC grid control to edit data however the dates returned to the controller have an invalid format and the ModelState is invalid.  I am using the New Zealand format of "dd/MM/yyyy".  All dates are displayed correctly in the grid and also while inline editing.  The problem seems to occur during the posting of data back to the controller.

**What I have tried**

From the countless articles related to this problem at stackoverflow, most point to an invalid culture setup.  However I have set the culture for the telerik grid in the layout file see below.  I have also set the global culture for asp.net mvc core in the startup file.

**Error Message**

"The value '20/10/2010 12:00:00 a.m.' is not valid for Due Date."

**Here is my code:**

- ASP.NET CORE KENDO
- UI for ASP.NET MVC

**Fiddler Raw Post:**

```
sort=&group=&filter=&InvoiceID=237&CompanyID=15&Description=Monthlyy&InvoiceDate=30%2F09%2F2010+12%3A00%3A00+a.m.&DueDate=20%2F10%2F2010+12%3A00%3A00+a.m.&Tax=0&Discount=0&Paid=true&Company.CompanyID=15&Company.Name=Engineering&Company.Address=&Company.Phone=&Company.Fax=&Company.CountryID=&Company.Comment=&InvoiceItems=
```

**Fiddler Raw Response:**

```
{"Data":[{"InvoiceID":237,"CompanyID":15,"Description":"Monthlyy","InvoiceDate":null,"DueDate":null,"Tax":0.0,"Discount":0,"Paid":true,"Company":{"CompanyID":15,"Name":"Engineering","Address":null,"Phone":null,"Fax":null,"CountryID":null,"Comment":null},"InvoiceItems":[]}],"Total":1,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":{"DueDate":{"errors":["The value '20/10/2010 12:00:00 a.m.' is not valid for Due Date."]},"InvoiceDate":{"errors":["The value '30/09/2010 12:00:00 a.m.' is not valid for Invoice Date."]}}}
```

**My View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GearBox.Models.Invoice>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Description);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Company.Name).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Multi(true).Search(true));
        columns.Bound(p => p.InvoiceDate).Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.DueDate).Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Paid).Width(80).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' #= Paid ? checked='checked' :'' # />");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
       .Input(true)
       .Numeric(false)
     )
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.InvoiceID))
        .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))        
        .Create(update => update.Action("Invoices_Create", "Invoice"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Invoices_Read", "Invoice"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Invoices_Update", "Invoice"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("Invoices_Destroy", "Invoice"))

    )
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
)
```

**Startup**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    app.UseRequestLocalization(BuildLocalizationOptions());
    ...
    app.UseKendo(env);
}

private RequestLocalizationOptions BuildLocalizationOptions()
{
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-NZ")          
    };

    var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-NZ"),
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    };

    return options;
}
```

**Header Section of Layout File**

```
<head>
       ... 
        @{              
            var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString();
        }

        <script src="@("https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/cultures/kendo.culture." + culture + ".min.js")"></script>

        <script>
            //Set the current culture
            kendo.culture("@culture");
        </script>
        ....
</head>
```

**Model**

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    [DataType("Integer")]
    //[Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(15)]      
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Invoice Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
           ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Due Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
           ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
```

**Editor Template**

```
@model DateTime?

@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:80%" })))
```

Comment: had you set date format in MVC model?

Comment: @Krushnakant Ladani - yes I have.  I will post model shortly.

Comment: @KrushnakantLadani i added the important bits of the model.

Comment: Try "column.Bound(p => p.DueDate).Width(130).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");" in Kendo grid

Comment: @Vijai,  thanks - I have already tried that. Additionally if I swap the format round to MM/dd/yyyy then it still gives an error.   Its like the post event is swapping the day and month which cause an error when the month value is above 12.

Comment: Check the date format given in the file 'Date.cshtml' in the folder Shared\EditorTemplates and Why you have given 'ApplyFormatInEditMode = false' It should be true, Isn't?

Comment: @Vijai I have updated the question to show the editor template at the bottom - thanks for your help.

Comment: In Date.cshtml use "@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
)"

Comment: @Vijai that still gives me an error:  The value '20/10/2010 12:00:00 a.m.' is not valid for Due Date.  I have also tried using ParseFormats.

Comment: Ok so I downloaded the asp.net core examples [here](https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-6-demos) and I have the same problem with dates.  It must be to do with my setup.   Any ideas?

Comment: @Vijai - OK after some more playing around I have noticed that if I change it too a datetimepicker and strip the time from the datepicker then it works.  I don't see why the time is being posted anyway when I just use the datepicker.  Any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: Did you use the following to include DatePicker  :  columns.Bound(p => p.DueDate).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("Date")

Comment: @Vijai, yes that's correct.  It correctly shows a Datepicker not a Datetimepicker.  But I can see from the output the time is being passed.

Comment: Check the file content of \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Date.cshtml. You may not have updated the format in it. @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
)

Comment: @Vijai, I can assure you that is exactly what I have in the Date.cshtml file.  I just copied and pasted to make sure.

Comment: @Vijai Solution posted. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of wasted time, the issue has been established to be related to the default regional settings for en-NZ on windows 10.  Changing the date format in regional settings from AM and PM to a.m. and p.m. solved the issue.  This is a short term workaround.